# How do I change the local path for VSO?

Tags: azure-devops

VSO has my local path set to "C:\Users\david\Source\Workspaces\Workspace" and that's too long for some of the path/filenames in our projects.

How can I set it to something shorter? (We are using VSO on TFS, not on Git.)

thanks - dave

Comment: FYI - the two source control systems provided within both TFS and VSO are TFVC and Git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the [mapping for your workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg490753(v=vs.100).aspx).

I would shelve all of my changes, then move the workspace by remapping and then do a full get.